# How to orbit previously weight painted vertices in Blender?

Tags: mesh, weight-painting

[image: Weight Paint Capture]

Is there a way in blender to orbit around the vertices or vertex that was previously painted in Weight Paint? Like in the Add-on section? 
Im trying to clean up this hind leg mesh, but im having trouble positioning the camera to paint well.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at this operation here :

**Weight Paint mode**

1. Go to Navigation panel on the 3d View
2. Go to View Section.
3. Turn on lock to cursor.
4. I suggest installing the "Enhanced 3d Cursor" add-on so you can snap the cursor to the mesh surfaces.
5. Now your viewport camera is locked to the location of the 3d Cursor.

[image]

**In Edit Mode**

1. Go to View Menu on your 3d View Panel
2. Look for "View Selected"
3. Now your viewport perspective/orthographic view will rotate around the selected object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I know a useful tool! But it doesnt work for me in Weight Paint mode as I have a specific bone selected to paint on, so the camera rotates around the bone, not the vertex I put to :view Selected" :/

Comment: Thanks! :D but still... I just wish there was a more convenient way in Weight Paint mode than resetting the 3D cursor's location onto the vertices every sigle time :/